# Updating instead of inserting if the row already exists

Tags: mysql

I'm facing an issue with SQL at the moment, i have got a relation between two columns in a table like this they are linked together as an unique key (id, charid) and using that relation i want to determine if i want to insert it or not, so if the following already exists

`[charid: 1, id: 1]`

I want to update it instead of inserting a new row, however if we insert a row like this and charid 1, id 1 already exists, that's OK and we can insert it.

`[charid: 1, id: 1]`

How can i correctly do this? I heard this could be done by using restrictions with the columns.

Comment: Is the unique key also the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE R 
SET R.COLUMN = VALUE 
FROM dbo.TABLE1 AS R
INNER JOIN dbo.TABLE2 AS P 
       ON R.charid = P.id
```

**Edit, actually you need a subquery with a "WHERE EXISTS" clause.  Will update in a bit.

```
UPDATE R
SET R.COLUMN = VALUE
FROM dbo.TABLE1 AS R
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT P.id
                 FROM dbo.TABLE2 AS P
                WHERE R.charid = P.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, when you have a primary key or two, you can do the following instead:

(Please note: You do need atleast one primary key for this)

`INSERT INTO arcade (id, charid, highscore) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE highscore = ?`

this makes it so that when there's a duplicate key, it updates the row instead of trying to insert something!